# VB.NET - Access to path %appdata% is denied

Tags: vb.net, path, appdata

I was making a mod installer for a Minecraft community, when I ended with this problem:

[image: Error description]

Here's my code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

            Button1.Enabled = False
            Button2.Enabled = False
            ComboBox1.Enabled = False
            Button1.Text = "DOWNLOADING... DO NOT QUIT!"



    Dim selected As String
    Dim issel As Boolean
    issel = False
    selected = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    If selected = "Minecade Mod 1.7.2" Then
        selected = "5"
        issel = True
    End If
    If selected = "Minecade Mod 1.7.2 with OptiFine Standard" Then
        selected = "3"
        issel = True
    End If
    If selected = "Minecade Mod 1.7.2 with Optifine Ultra" Then
        selected = "4"
        issel = True
    End If
    If selected = "Minecade Mod 1.7.2 with Optifine Standard and Minecade Capes" Then
        selected = "1"
        issel = True
    End If
    If selected = "Minecade Mod 1.7.2 with Optifine Ultra and Minecade Capes" Then
        selected = "2"
        issel = True
    End If

    If issel = False Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Selection! Try again.")

    Else
        Dim answ As Integer
        answ = MsgBox("You have chosen the mod with the ID of: " & selected & "." & vbCrLf & "Do you want to install this mod?", vbYesNo)
        If answ = 6 Then

            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\JOWD\MineCadeMod\1.7.2modded" & selected & ".zip") Then
                Dim answOverW As Integer = MsgBox("The file already exists on the download location. Do you wish to download the file again (NO) or do you want to continue with the old one (YES)? (Preferred: Yes)", vbYesNo)
                '6y7n


            End If


            'Installation process begins


            Try
                Dim dlPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "JOWD\MineCadeMod\1.7.2modded" & selected & ".zip"
                My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://files.casualnetwork.net/installers/moddedminec/1.7.2modded" & selected & ".zip", dlPath, "", "", False, 500, True)
                Dim Unpackandinstall As Boolean = MsgBox("Download succesful. Do you want to unpack and install the archieve?", vbYesNo)
                If Unpackandinstall = True Then
                    'UNPACK -------
```

'''Error occures inside the TRY tags here!'''

```
                    Try

                        Dim filePath As String
                        filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & ".minecraft\versions\1.7.2modded" & selected
                        Dim startPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "JOWD\MineCadeMod\1.7.2modded" & selected & ".zip"
                        Dim zipPath As String = filePath
                        Dim extractPath As String = filePath

                        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(filePath)

                        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath)

                        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)
                        MsgBox("Decompression, installation and finishing done! Ready to play!")
                    Catch ex As Exception

                        MsgBox("Error in decompression and installment proceidure." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Report to JOWD, as this should NOT happen!")
                        Button1.Enabled = True
                        Button2.Enabled = True
                        ComboBox1.Enabled = True
                        Button1.Text = "Download and Install!"

                    End Try
```

'''Error area ends!'''

```
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Button1.Enabled = True
                Button2.Enabled = True
                ComboBox1.Enabled = True
                Button1.Text = "Download and Install!"
                MsgBox("Download failed. Error code below!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Check the main topic for a possible solution, if nothing applies leave a reply!")
                Exit Sub
            End Try


        Else
            'installation process aborted.


        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I will be happy to answer any question related to my problem, I've tried to look help anywhere but nothing helps me!

Thanks.

---

### Read! Edited.

Regarding the 2 answers from David Sdot and Visual Vincent, - Their answers did not fix my problem.

I tried to use the following line on the code:

```
filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\.minecraft\versions\1.7.2modded" & selected
```

Same error occurred.

Still looking for more advices from you!

Leave a comment if you want the project file to test it out.

---

### Read! Edited.

Here's the source for the app, do your testing there!

http://files.casualnetwork.net/installers/moddedminec/source/MinecadeModInstaller_Min.zip

Comment: Have you set breakpoints to see where your getting the error at? I can see more than a few places you could be getting that from.

Comment: Narrow the code down to just the part where the error occurs. Note the **M** in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes I would like the project file please. I think it can have something to do with the extraction code...

Comment: Set breakpoints on create directory, then F10 once, if no error I bet it will on ExtractToDirectory... let me know.

Comment: I want the file too...

Comment: The file in now added into the original post.

Comment: In what line does the error throw? Is it the Filepath = Environment path line?

Comment: Regarding SomeNickName's and Mr CoDeXeR's comments: Please test for yourself, as I'm not familiar with breakpoints and debugging. Sorry if I sound bias, I haven't slept in straight 2 days.

Comment: Well, first of all your download doesn't exist: http://www.mydoomsite.com/Bilder/ModInst_Help1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here's my solution to your problem:

Here, I used a WebClient instead of My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile, since I think it's better. (You use whatever you want of course)

```
Dim Download As New WebClient
Download.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://files.casualnetwork.net/installers/moddedminec/1.7.2modded" & selected & ".zip"), dlPath)
```

---

I also noticed some stuff that had to be changed in your code.
For some reason you tried to zip your file into itself:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath)
```

Remove this. :)

---

And you also tried to extract .minecraft\versions\1.7.2modded to itself by doing this:

```
    Dim startPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\JOWD\MineCadeMod\1.7.2modded" & selected & ".zip"
    Dim zipPath As String = filePath
    Dim extractPath As String = filePath

    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)
```

Simply change zipPath from:

```
Dim zipPath As String = filePath
```

To:

```
Dim zipPath As String = startPath
```

Now the zipping should work fine :)

---

One more thing I noticed is that you couldn't skip the unzip part even if you pressed "No" in the MsBox. So I changed that code a little:

```
Dim Unpackandinstall As DialogResult
Unpackandinstall = MessageBox.Show("Download succesful. Do you want to unpack and install the archieve?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
If Unpackandinstall = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
    ...
End If
```

---

Here's the whole Try block:

```
        Try
            Dim Download As New WebClient
            Dim dlPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\JOWD\MineCadeMod\1.7.2modded" & selected & ".zip"
            Download.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://files.casualnetwork.net/installers/moddedminec/1.7.2modded" & selected & ".zip"), dlPath)

            Dim Unpackandinstall As DialogResult
            Unpackandinstall = MessageBox.Show("Download succesful. Do you want to unpack and install the archieve?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
            If Unpackandinstall = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then

                Try

                    Dim filePath As String
                    filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\.minecraft\versions\1.7.2modded" & selected
                    Dim startPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\JOWD\MineCadeMod\1.7.2modded" & selected & ".zip"
                    Dim zipPath As String = startPath
                    Dim extractPath As String = filePath

                    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(filePath)

                    'ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath)

                    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)
                    MsgBox("Decompression, installation and finishing done! Ready to play!")
                Catch ex As Exception

                    MsgBox("Error in decompression and installment proceidure." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Report to JOWD, as this should NOT happen!")
                    Button1.Enabled = True
                    Button2.Enabled = True
                    ComboBox1.Enabled = True
                    Button1.Text = "Download and Install!"

                End Try

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Button1.Enabled = True
            Button2.Enabled = True
            ComboBox1.Enabled = True
            Button1.Text = "Download and Install!"
            MsgBox("Download failed. Error code below!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Check the main topic for a possible solution, if nothing applies leave a reply!")
            Exit Sub
        End Try
```

---

And just replace

```
Download.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://files.casualnetwork.net/installers/moddedminec/1.7.2modded" & selected & ".zip"), dlPath)
```

With your My.Computer.Network code if you'd rather use that instead. :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & ".minecraft\versions\1.7.2modded" & selected
```

The path return by Environment.GetFolderPath has no **\** at the end and you prepended a dot instead.

```
filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\minecraft\versions\1.7.2modded" & selected
```

Comment: Is 1.7.2modded a folder or the beginning of the filename together with selected? if if folder there is issing another backslash. Another problem can be the folder name .minecraft I kknow win explorer can't created a directory with a dot at the beginning, maybe it is related to that.

Comment: The folder .minecraft already exists, however 1.7.2modded don't.